# Ruby on Rails devise, how to put a limit on how often a user can change their username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

`I have recently started working on a rails app and using devise as authentication. but I have ran into a wall. I would like to know if there's a way to set a period limit on how often a user may update their username. For example, if a User update their username today, they shouldn't be able to update it again until a 30day period has passed.
I have looked through devise docs, but nothing address that functionality, I have also search SO and the web but to no avail.

Any help would be very much be appreciated on how to go about it, or at least be pointed in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

I have added to the user model

```
after_save :name_last_updated

def name_last_updated
  if self.username_changed?
  self.name_last_updated_at = Time.now
end
```

but this does not update the colunm name_last_updated_at. any clues of what i am doing wrong will be helpful ^^ thanks!

so, after messing around with a few codes i figured an alternative way to go about this. I created a new column to track new time the user should be able to see the form to update his username.

```
def username_next_update
 self.username_next_update_at = self.username_last_update_at + 2.minutes
end
```

for learning and testing purposes i added +2.minutes
and i did a before_save on it.
 In my view i wrapped it around an if and else statement although i am quite confuse with the logic.

```
 <% if current_user.username_next_update_at < time.zone.now %>
********
<% end %>
```

but i expected to it to work only if it was > sign instead of <. any tips will be helpful or any better alternatives :)

Comment: You need to make this method a `before_safe`, so that it changes the column THEN saves it, not after_save.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create it from scratch.

Create a new column in the users table, call it `name_last_updated`, when the user updates their name for the first time, set that column to today's date. then every time a user wants to update their name, check that column and compare with today's date and see if 30 days have passed:

```
if Date.today - user.name_last_update < 30
  #display error
end
```

Comment: I would also add a callback method in the user model to make sure that we call this method every time the user model is updated.

Comment: hey Ahmad sorry for the late reply, the before_save definetely did the trick. now i am having some issues trying to define the proper method in the application.controller to restrict the user from updating their username until their 30days period has passed. if you could elaborate a little more on it, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @LordLJ Show me your controller where you update the user so I can help you better, do you have a customized controller or just whatever devise gives you?

Comment: oh i just use whatever devise provides

Comment: @LordLJ then you will have to override your registrations controller's `update` action. Look up how to override devises controllers. It's quite a bit of work, but you will learn a lot from the process.

Comment: sorry took so long to reply but i figured a different way around it, i will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use user updated_at column created by the devise gem and add a callback method in the user model to make sure that we call this method every time the user model is updated.

```
before_update { |user| user.write_attribute if user.is_permitted? }

def write_attribute
  self.user_name = params[:user][:user_name]
end

def is_permitted?
  if self.username_changed?
    Date.today - updated_at < 30
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `before_update` and specify which record has to activate the callback instead of using `after_save`.

I would do something like this:

```
before_update :name_last_updated, if: :username_changed?

def name_last_updated
 if (self.name_last_updated_at.to_date + 30.days) < Date.today
  self.update(name_last_updated_at: Time.now)
 end
end
```